# How to backup a file by date located in a remote server

Tags: linux, shell

I am trying to backup a ".jar" file which is located in a remote server. I wrote a shell script to do this but when I execute the script `ssh` is only working. Only one "jar" file is located in the directory. How can I do this?

```
#!/bin/bash

    backupFile()
    {
            ssh -t test@192.168.94.139 "cd /var/www/test.com ; bash"
            cp -a *.jar "$(date +"%Y%m%d-%H%M%S").tgz"

    }

    backupFile
```

Answer (score 0):

When I put whole command as an one command I got expected answer.

```
backupFile()

{
        ssh -t zissa@192.168.94.139 "cd /var/www/zissa.com ; cp -a *.jar "$(date +"%Y%m%d-%H%M%S").tgz""


}

backupFile
```

> Output:- 20181119-044717.tgz

Comment: You should use single quotes to execute the date command remotely: `ssh ... 'cd dir && cp -a *.jar "$(date +"%Y%m%d-%H%M%S").tgz"'`